# Library of cross-browser, degrading touch events, without the extra weight

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, touch, sencha-touch

I am building a single-page web application and I've been looking for a library that implements **just** a set of touch events, tap, taphold, swipe etc but doesn't:

- a) force me to use Sencha Touch
- b) come with tons of extra stuff that I don't want, without the ability to rip out just the events portion (Jquery mobile & Sencha Touch)

I did try to rip out just the events stuff from jquery mobile and the swipe events stopped working, not sure why.

My experiments with jquery mobile have frustrated me, it forces me to build my app "their" way, having to add data-role="page" to my container just to stop the page being blank when it's included, adding loading divs to the body (yuk). Since I already have a working app I don't want that.

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Cheers

Comment: check out http://microjs.com/#events 
or https://github.com/mythz/jquip (havent played with it but looks interesting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQM is now decoupled:

- http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/08/03/jquery-mobile-beta-2-released/

> **Widgets: Now decoupled for flexible builds**
>
> We’ve wanted to decouple all our widgets from the page plugin for a
>   long time now and we’re happy to announce that we finally landed this
>   change. So what exactly does decoupled mean anyway? Well, the
>   individual widgets and utilities have always been broken out into
>   separate script files. However, the page plugin was responsible for
>   handling the auto-initialization all of the official plugins found in
>   the markup at page creation. This situation made it impossible to
>   remove plugins you don’t need without causing errors, and generally
>   set a bad precedent for future widget additions.
>
> Now, pretty much all the UI widgets in the jQuery Mobile library are
>   completely decoupled so they can simply be deleted if not needed for a
>   particular project. This change allows you to dramatically reduce the
>   size of the library by only including the specific set of widgets or
>   features you need, in addition to the handful of required, core files.
>   While we still plan to do more decoupling and cleanup, the following
>   files are now decoupled and can safely be removed from the make file
>   before you do a custom build:
>
> - page header/content/footer
> - collapsible
> - controlgroup
> - fieldcontain
> - fixheaderfooter
> - button
> - checkboxradio
> - select
> - slider
> - textinput
> - links theming
> - listview
> - navbar
> - grid
>
> We will work on a dependency map because a few widgets rely on others
>   to work. For example, the button markup plugin is called by many of
>   the widgets above, so it can only be excluded but if you’re not using
>   any of the widgets that depend on buttons.
>
> We’re still working out our recommendations for mapping plugin
>   dependencies and decoupling things even further. Ultimately, this will
>   be surfaced in a download builder tool, so stay tuned!

You can head over to their GIT Repo and just download what you want:

- https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/tree/master/js

Comment: Are you aware of a dependency map? It's been a while since Beta 2 came out and I haven't seen any progress on this topic.

Comment: There is some direction on the Git repo wiki but nothing solid. I know they're going to deploy a Download Builder but still no ETA on this